# not able to re center layout and keep it left justified the views present in it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

So, I have a layout,and there are a couple of textviews in it,i'm trying to put all the views in the center and content of the views should be left justified,i'm not sure how to do that?

any inputs would be helpful,here's my xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="PTD Payments"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    />

                     <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/childOption1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="Option 1" />

            </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="#D3D3D3"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >
                    <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/childOption12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Annual TIA"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                     />

                    <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/childOption2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="Option 2" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="#D3D3D3"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >
                    <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/childOption13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Total Liability"
                    android:textColor="#ff0000"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                     />


                        <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/childOption3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textColor="#ff0000"
                    android:text="Option 3" />

            </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

It seems that relative layout works out, but I need to have some level of margin, i'm attaching an image on how it should look
[image]
I cannot share some part of the code due to privacy reasons

Comment: remove all the padding and margins for textview and use weightSum in LinearLayout tag, give wieghtsum = 2 and in textview tag give weight="1" to both textview. and also don't forget to give width of both textview to 0dp instead of wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:weightSum="2"
>
<TextView
 android:weight="1"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
 android:weight="1"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>        
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Says "No resource identifier found for attribute 'weight' in package 'android'"

Comment: sorry my mistake , android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is not working :(,btw i'm trying to do a expandable recycler view